# Secret message 01

Tags: cipher

116313333134261542156511321455121126113213151461123615112516114142

OK, so recently I made up a way of sending coded messages and I was just wondering how difficult it would be for someone to crack.
So let's say, for example, that you are in the army and you caught a suspected spy and you found a slip of paper on him with those numbers on it, exactly as they are above.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 17):

The first thing that's apparent is that

> the numbers are all in the range 1..6.

Since

> the number of letters in the alphabet is comparable to 6 squared,

it's natural to consider

> pairs of digits,

especially as

> the total number of digits is even. It's also a multiple of 3, but it doesn't look as if there's much repetition in the digit-triples, so that isn't a very promising line of attack.

An obvious guess is that

> letters are mapped into pairs of digits in some consistent way (there's already a pretty obvious guess, but let's be a little methodical here).

We then notice that

> there are quite a lot of 11 and 15, which would work nicely if those were A (first letter) and E (fifth letter).

So the obvious guess is

> that at least 11...16 are a..f.

Looking at what that gives us

> and considering whether then 21..26 are g..l, etc.,

we notice

> `ba.a.ced` which could be "balanced" if 26 is L

and now

> we just do the obvious thing, interpreting a digit pair ab as letter 6(a-1)+b,

and get

> `a_complete_and_balanced_breakfast` where each `_` is a (different, as it happens) "out-of-range" digit pair.

Seems like we've cracked it.

> (Is there an egg joke somewhere around here?)

In answer to the question of how difficult it is to crack,

> I think it took somewhere between three and five minutes to go through the process above, though I confess my very first thought on looking at the string of digits was pretty much the actual answer.